# Strange output in java 3

Tags: java

This java program prints out 12 and "Test". But, i can't figure it out why 12 has been printed.

```
 // Filename: MyClass.java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B("Test");
    }
}
class A {
    A() { this("1", "2"); }
    A(String s, String t) { this(s + t); }
    A(String s) { System.out.println(s); }
}
class B extends A {
    B(String s) { System.out.println(s); }
    B(String s, String t) { this(t + s + "3"); }
    B() { super("4"); };
}
```

Comment: `B(String)` calls A()` that is `super()` before executing its own code.

Comment: Java 3?? Wow... Anyway; **format your code**.

Comment: The default constructor of the super class is always called unless a different one is specified.

Comment: Did you ever run this in a terminal? Can you try using a debugger?

Comment: @matt - That's... weird. I didn't know that Java automatically calls super for you if you don't call it yourself. Seems like a behavior that just makes writing a compiler, plus reading the code as a human, more difficult.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this question except the poor formatting. This doesn't deserve these downvotes.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare how would you expect the superclass to be constructed if the default superclass constructor was not called?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Java is not the only language that does that.

Comment: What exactly is "Java 3"?

Comment: @Gendarme Yes there is, how class contructors are called and when is extremely well documented. Also, the code could EASILY be followed by simply debugging their own code

Comment: @redFIVE Essentially everything is well-documented. Not understand what is wrong with the code is one of the main reasons one asks questions on StackOverflow. The question is not *"How do constructors work in inherited classes?"*. The question is *"I am getting a totally different output than expected and I can't figure out why. What is wrong?"* which is totally fine.

Comment: @Gendarme, `I am getting a totally different output than expected and I can't figure out why. What is wrong?` and no debugging done is the perfect example of a terrible question

Comment: @BoristheSpider - I figure there are three other things it could do: 1 - It could do nothing. Just set aside the memory for the members of the superclass - leave it in whatever default state. 2 - It could consider it to be an error not to call super (seems like the best idea to me, if you want to force super to be called). 3 - It could at least implicitly call the super with the same signature, rather than the one that takes no arguments at all.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare 1. is obviously not an option. I suppose 2. or 3. would make some sort of sense - but that's just a design choice by the Java team.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever a constructor of an extending class is called, the compiler automatically calls `super()` before doing anything else if you don't call `super()` yourself (or `super(someParameter)` with parameters).

So

```
class B extends A {
    B(String s) { System.out.println(s); }
}
```

becomes

```
class B extends A {
    B(String s) { 
        super();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

That happens always. In your case, the constructor `A() { this("1", "2"); }` is called, which now calls `A(String s, String t) { this(s + t); }`, and finally `A(String s) { System.out.println(s); }`.

Keeping that in mind, it should be clear that `A() { this("1", "2"); }` is responsible for printing `12`.

Comment: if you add a default constructor for B, new B(s) will call supper()??

Comment: @Billydan yes, adding a default constructor wound not change anything when calling `new B(s)`. Even the default constructor would call `super()` when called by `new B()`

Comment: @Billydan Only if `dinner()` has been called.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems weird to me to have more constructors for just one class and-this("1", "2") I thought that is something wrong(hasn't any String or int..)  but in the debugging it doesn't show me any error. Also, I knew that the B class keeps A class properties but with that calling for the main class I thought it has to execute just B class instructions. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there is nothing wrong, there is implicit call to super constructor.
as class B extends class A whenever you create class B instance it invoke constructor of class A also - in you case its default constructor of class A which again invokes your class constructor "A(String s, String t)" and that again invokes "A(String s)". so, it gives output as 12 and Test. which is correct.